# Why PBS_NODEFILE and PBS_JOBID are not set in torque

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, pbs, torque

I want to submit a work to our school's cluster, but it seems that something went error with the environment variable. Here is a test PBS file

```
#PBS -N test
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -q ser
#PBS -V
#PBS -S /bin/bash

echo ${PBS_NODEFILE}
echo ${PBS_JOBID}
env
```

I can see the two variable in "env" but "echo" does not print this two variables, and I also can't use these variables in my script. For example "cat ${PBS_NODEFILE} > nodes" will output nothing. Why is this happen???

---

Well actually I found later that not only this two variables but all variables that is not passed from the current environment(by using -V), such as PBS_O_SHELL , cannot be used in the script. And the other environmental variables such as PATH can be printed normally

Comment: You have to make sure that your cluster is running PBS and not other resource manager **AND** you have to run your script using the `qsub` command, i.e. `qsub your_test_pbs_file.sh`.

Comment: oh thanks i think i have found what went error because i use qsub << EOF ..... EOF to submit the work so the ${PBS_NODEFILE} and ${PBS_JOBID} was replaced by blank...